# Django can't find templates with jinja2 engine

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I'm going to change django's template engines to jinja2, but after setting the setting.py of my project, jinja2 engines doesn't work, the followings are my codes.

```
settings.py
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
            'DIRS': [
                BASE_DIR / 'templates',
                     ],
            'APP_DIRS':True,
            'OPTIONS':{
                'environment':'emotion.jinja2.environment',
            
            }
        },
        
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

the following is jinja2.py

```
jinja2.py
def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update(
        {
            'static':static,
            'url':reverse,
        }
    )
    
    return env
```

But while I runserver, it seems like jinja2 doesn't work.
jinja2 doesn't search the file I want.

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine jinja2:

This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.
Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\Anaconda3\envs\Web\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\catalog\jinj.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\Anaconda3\envs\Web\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\catalog\jinj.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\Emotion\emotion\catalog\templates\catalog\jinj.html (Source does not exist)
```

The django engine is perfect work but I change the file name to test where it search.
While I rename it back to correct name, django's engine work, jinja2 doesn't.

My project name is 'emotion', which has a app name catalog.
html's path is emotion/catalog/templates/catalog/jinja.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting's path because you could be using the wrong url of DIRS in TEMPLATES of jinja2 in settings.py.

It should be

```
'DIRS': [
    BASE_DIR / 'catalog/templates',
]
```

instead of

```
'DIRS': [
    BASE_DIR / 'templates',
]
```